# GCP connect other user psql instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, psql, connect

We are a student group that wants to make a simple PostgreSQL project on google cloud.

I create database and tables etc. but I can't solve how my team-mates connect that database?

Comment: I get this error "PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud SQL Admin API has not been used in project"

Comment: So you can connect to database as you are able to create tables and database. If so, 1) You'll need to create users for your teammates, you can create users using cli: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/users/. 2) Please can you elaborate more on PERMISSION_DENIED error, what action are you trying to do when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can create users in the console to allow your team-mates to connect. Please follow the steps in the link for [Creating a User](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-users#creating).

As for the error message:  you need to enable [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/#enabling_the_api).